# absent/abscond - what etymology do they share?

Tags: etymology, roots

I was doing some writing today, and during the final editing process I came across a typo: I had misspelled "absent" as "abscent". I couldn't help but think of the word abscond. I wonder if it's true that the only etymological relation "absent" and "abscond" share is the latin *ab(s)*- (And I guess my bigger question is whether or not that is even the case)? Any insight would be welcome, even if this is kind of a silly question. Thanks!

Comment: *ab* = away. "**ab** away, down, from, off -- *absent, abduction, aberrant, abstemious, abnormal, abstract, absorb* http://www.virtualsalt.com/roots.htm

Comment: See also, http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abs-

Answer (score 2):

The online Oxford Dictionary gives no connection between these two words ([absent](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/absent?q=absent) / [abscond](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/abscond?q=abscond)) other than the Latin *ab(s)-* meaning 'away, from'. The origin of *absent* is *abesse* (*-esse* = 'to be'), while the origin of abscond is *abscondere* (*-condere* = 'stow').

So we have:

absent = be away/from

abscond = stow (or hide) away/from